# Is that a malicious code?

Tags: themes, security

Recently I have downloaded a wordpress theme . I use Theme Authenticity Checker (TAC) (http://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/) plugin to find any malicious data . According to it's report the theme contains some encrypted code like this

```
$pid        = base64_decode($_POST['control_id']);
```

I don't understand , is it really harmful for site ? If yes , then how can I get rid of this ?

Comment: What is the theme?

Comment: Without seeing the theme code in context I couldn't say with confidence but I'd guess this is not malicious. You should be able to `echo` or `var_dump` the `$pid` variable and exactly what the encoded (not encrypted) data is.

Comment: This is the site smile auction theme

Comment: What is the different between encoded and encrypted ?

Answer (score 2):

That is most likely a false positive : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors

`base64_decode` is not bad in of itself : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

The plugin is not smart enough to know a legitimate reason to use `base64_decode` of which there are many.

Comment: Thanks , do you know any other plugin which will be smart enough ?

Comment: No I don't use "security" plugins , sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seems to be harmful. Looks like, `base64_decode` function is just used to decrypt the encrypted the numeric IDs. Common reason for such encryption/decryption is to hide the real ID of the database record.

TAC plugin pointed it out because `base64_decode` function is widely used in malicious scripts to hide programming code which is later used in `eval` for execution.